# Using ffmpeg apply filters to a Video memory stream. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, azure, video, ffmpeg, memorystream

I have a requirement where I will be downloading my Video file data present on an Azure BLOB. I will get this Video file data in the form of a MemoryStream.

Is there any way that using ffmpeg I can process this MemoryStream e.g removing audio, blurring video etc?

If its not possible then I will have to download the BLOB file somewhere on my Server in the form of .mp4 and then do the processing by ffmpeg. But actually I want to avoid this step of creating file on hard disk downloaded via MemoryStream.

Here is the sample/pseudo code:

```
public void ProcessVideoFile(string containerName, string blobURI)
{
    CloudBlockBlob blob = GetBlockBlobReference(containerName, blobURI);

    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        blob.DownloadToStream(memStream);

        // Process this memStream using ffmpeg for different filters e.g blurring, remove audio etc.
        // ......................
    }
}
```

Comment: Can somebody help plz? No answer yet